# Booting to Windows from BIOS menu works, but booting to Windows 10 from GRUB gives error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Windows 10 on a machine in UEFI mode on a GPT partitioned drive. I then installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a different partition on the same hard drive. When I boot, I can get to GRUB and boot to Ubuntu fine, and the Windows 10 on /dev/sdb1 shows up, but if I select that, I get an error saying that Windows failed to start (0xc000000e error).

However, if I select the windows partition in my BIOS, Windows 10 works fine and boots error-free.

I'd really like to figure out how to get my Windows 10 working properly from my GRUB, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

In boot-repair, it says my Ubuntu is currently in Legacy Mode.

I have the Windows 10 install DVD and a bootable Ubuntu flash drive.

Comment: With Ubuntu in Legacy mode you can't use it to boot Windows in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I needed to burn a Windows ISO image to a DVD in order to get it to work. I tried multiple times through the USB Windows ISO I had and it never worked. From there, repair the windows install through GRUB and it worked from there.